# how to hide row with rowspan

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I have a table with `rowspan` at starting and ending column. Layout is:

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Hide" />
<div id="result">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Hide</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>col2</td>
         <td>col3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>Col1</td>
         <td>col2</td>
         <td>col3</td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and the jquery code is:

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').toggle();
});
```

It will be expected to hide the row1 and row2 simultaneously as there is only one chekbox for both row (rowspan), but it is not happening. It is only hiding row1.

How it can be resolved?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/infomamun/a191jffw/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9rd7mhny/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a check to see if the next row has less rows - if it does it is a rowspan so you can hide it:

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    var row = $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr'),
        rowspan = row.next();

    row.toggle();
    if (rowspan.children().length < row.children().length) {
        rowspan.toggle();
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a191jffw/5/)

**Edit**

As per comment - solution for any amount of rowspans in any column:

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){    
    $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
        var row = $(this),
            columns = row.children('td[rowspan]'),
            rowsToSpan = 0;

        row.toggle();

        if (columns.length) {
            columns.each(function() {
                var thisRowSpan = parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan'));
                if (thisRowSpan > rowsToSpan) {
                    rowsToSpan = thisRowSpan;
                }
            });

            var nextRow = row.next();
            for (var i = 1; i < rowsToSpan; i++) {
                nextRow.toggle();
                nextRow = nextRow.next();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a191jffw/8/)

Comment: your code will work if rowspan is for two rows, but what if rowspan for 3 or more rows? Yow is the best in this context. Anyway, thanks to you too.

Comment: I'll update a fiddle - will the rowspan attribute always be on the first column?

Comment: No, it could be on any column

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid updated the answer - your selected answer will only work if the rowspan on the checkbox row is the correct number: see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a191jffw/9/

Comment: Don't know why @Yow's solution is not working now. But at that time I checked his code on both row with/without rowspan. Anyway, I just have shifted my acceptance from Yow to you. Both of you are great!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
$('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').toggle();
    $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('tr').next().toggle();
    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a191jffw/4/)

I used `.next()` to select the next tr that should be hidden

Comment: It will work only if there are three rows, but if there are four rows, the 3rd and 4th rows will be hidden if checkbox is checked in row 3. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infomamun/a191jffw/6/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**
Let's do it shorter, and working for every case :
[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a191jffw/16/)

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {

        // let's take each row, and its rowspan value
        var thistr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var howmuch = thistr.find('td[rowspan]').attr('rowspan');
        if(typeof(howmuch)==='undefined') {howmuch=1;}        
    
        // looping and toggling
        for(var i=0; i<howmuch; i++) {
            thistr.toggle();
            thistr=thistr.next();
        }
    });
});
```

---

### old post :

[This Updated JsFiddle will do](http://jsfiddle.net/a191jffw/7/)

You have to take the first parent TR, then start a loop to the sibling TRs depending on the "rowspan" value of it...

```
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    var aa = $('#result > table').find('input:checkbox:checked').closest('td[rowspan]');
    var thetr=aa.closest('tr');

    for(var i=0; i<aa.attr('rowspan'); i++) {
        thetr.toggle();
        thetr=thetr.next();
    }
});
```

The syntax may be perfectible, but you get the idea.

By the way, it works *even if multiple rowspans exists next to each other*, which isn't the case of the accepted answer, I think...?

---

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But @Pete did it with less code and complexicity. See the above solution of Pete. Anyway I upvoted your answer too.

Comment: Sorry, Although at first I thought @Pete's solution is best as less complexicity, but later I found your one is best. It is because your code can find rowspan of 2 or more (up to unlimited number of rowspan) whether Pete's can work for only one rowspan(two rows linked).I think your solution is best. I accepted your answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the vote. I just edited my post : The accepted answer doesn't work with multiple rowspans following each others, as there's no check for the "hide button" value in the next rows...

Comment: Thank you, I hope it will help others as well, it was an interesting question

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid - this doesn't work for the columns where there is no rowspan: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a191jffw/10/ - the updated fiddle only works because there is an errant rowspan on the last cell

Comment: U're right, I've just modified it, it now works way better, and with shorter code. See updated answer above.

Comment: The new update won't work either as it will only take the first rowspan attribute and apply it to all toggles - see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/a191jffw/15/, try hiding the first and second checkboxes, you will see it also hides the third as it is using your rowspan attribute from the first row on the second row

Comment: @Pete : Yup, forgot the each(). Corrected.